# ssis visual studio 2010 and excel timestamp as date

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ssis-2012

fairly new to SSIS

I have a file for example called Data20100101

I want to use the 20100101 as a column to mark the date column

E.G

DATE (This will be derived from the file name please), ID , Item, Department

20100101 00:00:00 (happy just to have the date), 1, Cabinet, Furniture
20100101 00:00:00 (happy just to have the date), 2, Cooker, Kitichen

Update:

I have found to store the path of the file into a variable

DataLoadDir  c:\SSIS\Files\Sales

need to know how to store the file name into a variable as it is dynamic

then I need to use the Derived Column to call the part of the file name to use as my Census Date - need help with the code with this

any ideas team please?

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable "FilePath" in SSIS and then pass it from DTEXEC. Then you can use expressions to get the Date part into a Date variable and use it.

Anotther way..You can lookup the file if it is unique enough from a folder directly. Use the For Each Loop with "for each file enumerator".